# AngularJS ng-href and svg xlink

Tags: html, angularjs, svg, angularjs-directive, xml-namespaces

I'd like some input on using xml namespaced attributes with angular.

The problem is angular comes with a couple of directives to handle writing attributes such as href and src when angular has parsed the expresssions (otherwise the browser will try to load `{{mymodel.myimage}}` as a url)

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/booleanAttrs.js#L329

The problem I'm facing is that I'm using angular to output svg together with D3 and since angular doesn't have a way to output `xlink:href` I was stuck.

I created a custom directive that outputs xlink:href

```
app.directive('ngXlinkHref', function () {
  return {
    priority: 99,
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function (scope, element, attr) {
      var attrName = 'xlink:href';
      attr.$observe('ngXlinkHref', function (value) {
        if (!value)
          return;

        attr.$set(attrName, value);
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Full demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/cMhGRh

But it seems that if I don't manually add xlink:href to the element, the svg image will not render.

Any suggestions on how to best handle xml namespaces / svg together with angular would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I didn't find an answer to your question, but thank you for posting the Plunker. I used it for my own angular SVG binding.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You can use `ng-attr-<some attribute>`

`ng-attr-xlink:href="{{xxx}}"` works for me.

---

Note that you also need an empty `xlink:href=""` as initial value. –  Derek Hsu

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @Siddharth, Actually it does.

The question is not simply about custom directives. Indeed, @Leon wanted some input on using xml namespaced attributes with angular and suggestions on how to best handle xml namespaces / svg together with angular. To resolve his problem, he was even writing custom directives.

I am pointing out that custom directives are not necessary. Angularjs already has `ng-attr` which does the job for him.

Comment: How about a fiddle to prove this? It's not working for me...  `<svg><use ng-attr-xlink:href="#icon-{{notification.type}}"></use></svg>`

Comment: @sheriffderek, here you go [angularjs ng-attr example](http://jsfiddle.net/HybridForce/vcs31Lym/). Note that you also need an empty `xlink:href=""` as initial value.

Comment: I was hoping to use it with <use> -- so that I can target pieces of a sprite. I don't really have any reason to put an image in an svg.

Comment: AH --- actually --- I didn't read it properly. Here is a codepen where I have it working the way I want. Why don't you put the actual directive code in the answer? Then it would be correct. : )  - http://codepen.io/sheriffderek/pen/EdCDr   THANKS!

Comment: +1, This works for me, but it's VERY picky. You meed the empty xlink:href="" AFTER the dynamic ng-attr-xlink:href. Also, I don't think this works for earlier versions of Angular.

Answer (score 19):

If, like me, you're looking for a way to add images to svg, you can do so adding:

```
xlink:href="" ng-href="{{ foo }}"
```

Example:

http://jsbin.com/sigoleya/1/edit?html,js,output

Where I found the solution:

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/7697

Comment: this is pretty brilliant. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

I ran into a similar problem when trying to output a value for `xlink:href` that's tied to the model. Based on the user's chosen `<option>` in a `<select>` control, I was trying to show a dynamic SVG icon via the `xlink:href` attribute of the `<use>` element.

I found [a thread about this](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/7697) in the GitHub Issues for AngularJS. Based on the discussion there, it appears that because a viable workaround exists, they've effectively tabled a fix by moving it to the Backlog milestone.

What ultimately worked for me was inspired by this JSBin:

http://jsbin.com/sigoleya/1/edit?html,js,output

Here's the code I used in my template:

```
<svg class="icon" data-ng-class="category.iconName">
  <use xlink:href="" data-ng-href="{{'#' + category.iconName}}">
</svg>
```

Given a `category.iconName` of `icon-music`, for example, Angular sets the `xlink:href` dynamically to `#icon-music`, which references the `<svg id="icon-music">` element further up on the same page.

As others have noted, what's key is setting a blank `xlink:href=""` attribute on the element where you call the `ngHref` directive. Attribute order does not seem to matter. Using `ng-attr-xlink:href="{{xxx}}"` (as mentioned in Derek Hsu's answer) did not work for me.

All of this assumes Angular 1.3.36.

Comment: thank u so much it works for me...ng-attr-xlink:href="{{model}}" didnt work for me.....

Comment: coffeescript: <use xlink:href="" ng-attr-href="\#{{$ctrl.name}}"></use>

Answer (score 6):

I solved the same problem with the following modules:

Module for SVGs:

```
var app = angular.module('Svgs', []);

angular.forEach([
    { ngAttrName: 'ngXlinkHref', attrName: 'xlink:href' },
    { ngAttrName: 'ngWidth', attrName: 'width' },
    { ngAttrName: 'ngHeight', attrName: 'height' }
], function (pair) {

    var ngAttrName = pair.ngAttrName;
    var attrName = pair.attrName;

    app.directive(ngAttrName, function (IeHelperSrv) {

        return {

            priority: 99,

            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

                attrs.$observe(ngAttrName, function (value) {

                    if (!value) return;

                    attrs.$set(attrName, value);
                    if (IeHelperSrv.isIE) element.prop(attrName, value);
                });
            }
        };
    });
});
```

Module for IE detection:

```
angular.module('IeHelper', []).factory('IeHelperSrv', function () {

    return {
        isIE: checkForIE.isIE,
    }
});

var checkForIE = {
    init: function () {
        this.isIE = (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('MSIE') != -1);
    }
};

checkForIE.init();
```

HTML:

```
<!-- image has initial fake source, width and height to force it to render -->
<image xlink:href="~/Content/Empty.png" width="1" height="1"
    ng-xlink-href="{{item.imageSrc}}"
    ng-width="{{item.width}}" ng-height="{{item.height}}"
    ng-cloak
    />
```

Comment: When the xlink:href wasn't working for me, I had to re-read this post. The key here is that YOU NEED A FAKE VALUE TO START WITH. Without it, the image will not render even with the correct attribute. Leaving this comment to help other TL;DR dummies like me. Thanks Danny!

Comment: @fractalspawn You are welcome. I was going to add this comment to the answer, then I saw I already put this in a comment above the HTML :-)

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else having this problem due to Angular/Angular UI Router in HTML5 mode, I came up with a straightforward fix to enable svg sprite icons to work with their xlink:href attribute and the  tag.

Gist is here: https://gist.github.com/planetflash/4d9d66e924aae95f7618c03f2aabd4a3

```
app.run(['$rootScope', '$window', function($rootScope, $window){
 $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function(event){
    $rootScope.absurl = $window.location.href;
});

<svg><use xlink:href="{{absurl+'#svgvID'}}"></use></svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem where I was using Ajax to load the svg spritesheet onto the page. If I had a on the page before the spritesheet was loaded, it would fail and would not resolve once the spritesheet was avaialble. Any added to the dom after the spritesheet was loaded were fine. I had to delay putting the items in the dom until after the spritesheet finished loading.

This only affected IOS. All other browsers didn't care about the order.

Answer (score 0):

This took me more time than I would've wanted. Around 20-30 minutes.

If I understand correctly, any failed loading on image element will **render that element useless in the future**. I believe it's something similiar @GeekyMonkey is saying. If angular binding system has set xlink:href initially to null, Image element wont work anymore, even if we have valid value in the future.

Here is solution, notice how I have wrapped image element inside g element, using ng-if directive. That makes sure we will bind against image only when a correct value is available.

```
<g ng-if="vm.svgMap.background != null">
    <image
        ng-attr-xlink:href="{{vm.svgMap.background.image | trusted}}"
        ng-attr-width="{{vm.svgMap.background.width}}"
        ng-attr-height="{{vm.svgMap.background.width}}"

        xlink:href=""

        width="1"
        height="1"
        x="0"
        y="0"></image>
</g>
```

As others said,  the order of attributes are important as well. To ensure that angularJS allows us to bind image element, we'll also have to trust that resource, I've done it through filter (it's the one in xlink:href attribute):

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('myTool').filter('trusted', TrustedFilter);

    function TrustedFilter($sce) {
        return function(url) {
            return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(url);
        };
    };
}());
```