# Binding Elements in Angular when using Xlink specifications

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, xlink

I have a page which starts with Raw XML and using Angular Directives and CSS to transform that Raw XML into a webpage with editable fields, buttons, and labels.  Since a piece of the data is relational in nature, I am using loose xLink specifications to create a "source node" with the data which may be reference multiple times on the page.

On my page, the name node for a team is editable.  Currently, my link function for the team node directive has a function that if it has the attribute "source", use that id to pull the HTML for the team node with that id attribute already on the page(When this directive is fired, the team nodes at the top of the XML have already been processed and have ng-transclude, scope, and HTML nodes already added because of the directive running on the node.)

Currently, my page looks as renders visually correctly; however, I have two issues:
1) The teams within the game node hierarchy are not editable (which is enforced by the directive).
2) And more importantly, when I edit the team of the top (Change name of team 1 from "Yankees" to "New York Yankees," the reference is not updated until I refresh the page.

Does anyone have any advice on how best to bind these elements together?

Data on page load:

```
<all>
  <teams>
    <team id="1">
      <name>Yankees</name>
    </team>
    <team id="2">
      <name>Red Sox</name>
    </team>
  </teams>
  <games>
    <game>
      <date>
      <teams>
        <hometeam>
           <team source="1" />
        </hometeam>
        <hometeam>
           <team source="2" />
        </hometeam>
      </teams>
    </game>
  </games>
</all>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parsing SVG with AngularJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17890931/parsing-svg-with-angularjs)

Comment: Here's an [unrelated question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15895483/) which may help