# Angular 1 component lazy load request error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This one has me stumped, but might be a simple on/off if someone has dealt with it before. I have an angular 1 app using a bunch of components. When the component is loaded by angular, I get a network request that looks like this:

http://localhost:5555/%7B[%7B%20'

When I decode this, I get a `{[{ '` which indicates it is appearing for some reason due to my custom brackets:

```
$interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{[{');
$interpolateProvider.endSymbol('}]}');
```

This random network request, when I attempt to decipher the request initiator, seems to be coming from component lazy loading (which I have never touched in any way).

[image: sample network request stack]

The weirder thing is that sometimes this request goes through as a 200 success with no response, and sometimes it gets canceled, showing a red error. The error doesn't ever appear as a console error and doesn't disrupt the page in any way.

I have no idea why this is appearing, or how to fix it, so I'm open to any suggestions!

**Edit**: Adding fiddle that somewhat replicates my setup. Unfortunately, I can't get the actual network request issue to replicate. https://jsfiddle.net/runfaj/0retoa1m/

Comment: The question lacks http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . It doesn't even mention how lazy loading is done. It isn't supported by the framework itself.

Comment: You clearly didn't read the description: "seems to be coming from component lazy loading (which I have never touched in any way)". I don't know if that is the actual cause or not hence the "seems" part.

Comment: I clearly did and it clearly isn't clear enough. If you don't have idea what 'lazy loading' it is, how anybody else can? I don't see how it can be caused by Angular built-in directives, so it's either an error in third party directive or human mistake where an expression was specified where it wasn't expected. Any way, the question cannot be answered without a way to replicate the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's the main problem. I don't know where this issue is coming from or what is causing it, so I don't have any way to replicate it. If I did, I wouldn't be posting the question here. I've given as much possible info that I can from my findings, but this is asking for help from anyone that might have run into the issue before.

Comment: Nope, nothing specific enough. I'd suggest to start with searching your code base (including third-party) for `{{ '` and then checking which of these expressions can lead to template load or other $http requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution completely by accident. I was running into this issue for a couple months, but when I changed one of my components recently, I noticed the network requests had changed to include my new changes.

It came down to a `<use>` tag like the following:

```
<use xlink:href="{[{ '#icon-' + $ctrl.renderedName }]}"></use>
```

In researching the reason, this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15895483/angular-ng-href-and-svg-xlink) explained the fix and this [angular doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/interpolation) says that some tags are picky about attributes, so the solution is to change it to this:

```
<use xlink:href="" ng-attr-xlink:href="{[{ '#icon-' + $ctrl.renderedName }]}"></use>
```

It is strange that the stack trace in the question was appearing like that, since the xlink:href should not be calling any type of jquery/angular request as it is a native browser lookup.